# Transfer of images from iPhone incomplete

Tags: windows-10, iphone

A
I connected the iPhone via USB and imported all images to the Win10 machine. When I compared source and drain a lot of images were missing.

B
So I switched to the old method with copy/paste. When I did this I selected 162 images by ctrl-A and pasted them to a new folder. Afterwards only 91 images were found in the new folder.

The Win10 is 22H2 and the IOS is 17.3.

Comment: Why are you not using iTunes and iCloud to synchornize your photos?  You sentence, "When I compared source and drain a lot of images were missing.", is not exactly clear as it appears to be using an incorrect word.

Comment: On the iPhone side 162 images were found and selected, but on the Win10 side only 59 images arrived with the copy/paste.